# How to make a statistic request without response?

Tags: javascript, image, iframe, browser, request

My team make statistic API designed without response(Is it a good design?). It mean front-end need to make a statistic request and cancel the requset immediately. Otherwise the request will make browser keep beeing loading status when start loading a page.

I can not use XMLHttpRequest() because of cross domain and no CROS headers. I try to use Image() to make the request and delete image object immediately. But it still make browser stuck.

I try to use iFrame to make the request. But my supervisor said it's the same as Image().

Dose anybody know how to make a requset without response and browser not get stuck?

Sorry for my English. I know is sucks.

Comment: `(Is it a good design?)` - clearly it isn't, because it screws up the clients trying to use it. They should AT LEAST close the socket

Comment: And an image **is** a request, and if you manage to get a browser to crash by including a simple tracking image, you're clearly doing something wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I agree with you. But they refuse to change that design and the resone is 'no need'. I think they just lazy.

Comment: There should be at least a status response for the client to know if its request was success or not, I think.

Comment: The usual way is to just serve up an actual image that is 1 x 1px and then catch the request with the querystring on the server, it should be simple. If you don't serve anything, and just make requests for images that aren't there, it clearly won't work.

Comment: `I can not use XMLHttpRequest()` - as you are not expecting a response anyway, you CAN use `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @JaromandaX Good point. Browser will prevent response because of cross domain. Maybe this a perfect solution.

Comment: @adeneo Yes. That make sense. But I am not the API develper. Maybe I should insist on arguing with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using XMLHttpRequest with an appropriately set timeout and with proper "exception" handling (you WILL get a timeout) - you should be able to control the request so it doesn't adversely effect the browser

```
function pingAPI(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.timeout = 300; // 300 milliseconds - adjust as required
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.addEventListener('timeout', function(e) {
        // you may not even need this
    });
    xhr.send();
}
```